# Can stem cells from male convert to cells of female-only organs, and vice versa?

Tags: stem-cells

As we know, stem cells can convert to different cells of other organs, can male use their own stem cells to convert it into cells of female-only organs(and vice versa)?

Comment: Well a stem cell is what every cell comes from, they go through differentiation to become any cell in the body. So theoretically, yeah that kind of differentiation could occur, you'd just need the correct stimulation.

Comment: @user19270 no, you are **completely** incorrect. There is no "stimulation" to change an X chromosome into a Y, or vice versa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming you are talking about embryological stem cells and embryological development of genitalia.

The answer is no.

Male stem cells have XY chromosomes. Y chromosome is the sex determining chromosome with SRY gene that determines testes development. Absence of the Y chromosome leads to female development by default. That is why XX forms women and there are people with only one X chromosome which are women. (Turner's syndrome)

It might be possible that SRY gene undergoes a mutation and the gene isn't expressed. There are Y chromosome linked diseases.

You should read up about Y chromosome and development of genitalia.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Y_chromosome
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Development_of_the_reproductive_system